# Simple binomial distribution problem: why is my approach not working?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

From Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists, 9th edition:

> According to a study published by a group of University
>   of Massachusetts sociologists, approximately
>   $60\%$ of the Valium users in the state of Massachusetts
>   first took Valium for psychological problems. Find the
>   probability that among the next $8$ users from this state
>   who are interviewed,
>
> (a) exactly $3$ began taking Valium for psychological
>   problems;
>
> (b) at least $5$ began taking Valium for problems that
>   were not psychological.

I got part (a) right, but I'm unsure why my approach for part (b) isn't working. My approach:

Let $X$ denote the number of users who began taking Valium for non-psychological reasons. Then the problem is asking us to find $P(X\geq5)$. Note that the probability that a Valium user first took Valium for non-psychological problems is $40\%$ (which is $100-60\%$).

In terms of binomial distributions, this would be:

$${8 \choose 5}(0.4^5)(0.6^3)+{8 \choose 6}(0.4^6)(0.6^2)+{8 \choose 7}(0.4^7)(0.6)+{8 \choose 8}(0.4^8)(0.6^0)$$

Calculating this, I got an answer of $0.1736704$.

The book did the following:
[image]

Now, someone correct me if I'm wrong, because I feel like I'm going crazy here—didn't they calculate the probability of at least $5$ users taking Valium for problems that *were* psychological? I just calculated that and got their answer. But the problem asks for *not* psychological.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working is right.

They computed the probability that at least $5$
 began taking Valium for psychological problem.

Comment: @amd thanks for pointing the typo.